# How can I sort a list of struct pointers according to one of the struct's fields?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this code:

```
struct nod
{
    nod *vCap;
    int vCost;
    char vInfo;
}; 

list<nod*> vList;

for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    nod *vTmp;
    vTmp->vCost=i;
    vTmp->vInfo='a';
    vList.push_back(vTmp);
}
```

How can I sort the list by the `vCost` value?

Comment: Your code will crash anyway (if you're lucky), since you don't intialize `vTmp` before dereferencing it. Oh, it won't even compile, since you call `nod->vCost` and not `vTmp->vCost`. Why use pointers to `nod` anyway, instead of just `nod` values? If you have a good reason for this, no problem. If not, you should delve a little deeper into the basics of C++. Keep in mind that `std::list` is already a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a custom comparator to compare the field you're interested in:

```
struct compare_nod_by_cost {
    bool operator()(nod const * a, nod const * b) {
        return a->vCost < b->vCost;
    }
};
```

Then you can provide it as the comparator for `list::sort`:

```
vList.sort(compare_nod_by_cost());
```

In C++11, you can compress this into a lambda:

```
vList.sort([](nod const * a, nod const * b) {return a->vCost < b->vCost;});
```

(Note that you almost certainly want to store objects, rather than pointers, in your list; in that case, change the comparator's pointer arguments to references).

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda:

```
vList.sort([](const nod * a, const nod * b ) { return a->vCost < b->vCost; });
```

Comment: error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '['
error C2059: syntax error : ']'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
error C2227: left of '->vCost' must point to class/struct/union/generic type is ''unknown-type''
error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
error C2227: left of '->vCost' must point to class/struct/union/generic type type is ''unknown-type''
error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: I know it is an official standard already, but due to its rather young existence and compiler implementations, just a little comment on the C++11ness of lambdas would be enough.

Comment: @alex The errors are due to the fact that lambdas are a C++11 feature, for which you need at least VS2010. Look at Mike's answer for a C++03 solution.

Comment: @ChristianRau: More importantly, the OP said she has MSVC, and MSVC does support it in its current version. But you're right, legacy versions don't.

Answer (score 2):

If the normal or natural ordering for a `nod` is by cost, then you might want to define its `operator<` to do that:

```
struct nod{
    nod*vCap; 
    int vCost;
    char vInfo;

    bool operator<(nod const &other)  { return vCost < other.vCost; }
};
```

Then, of course, you almost certainly want to create a `list<nod>` instead of a `list<nod*>`. Having done that, sorting items in a list will just be `vList.sort();`.

Just FWIW, you also need to fix a typo in your definition of `nod` (you have a comma instead of a semicolon between the definitions of `vCost` and `vInfo`.

Comment: Nice idea, but he uses a list of `nod*` and not just `nod` so the operator won't work.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes, that's part of the point -- he should almost certainly be using a list of nod instead of nod *.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: In that case, you should probably make that clear in the answer. Simply following your instructions will cause the list of pointers to be sorted incorrectly.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: yeah, I s'pose. Done.